# Is there a category such that if $\mathbb{R}$ is viewed as an object, we have that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the Euclidean distance function?

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

Viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as an object of the category of metric spaces and metric maps, we have that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the distance function $$d(x,y) = \max\{d_\mathbb{R}(x_0,y_0),d_\mathbb{R}(x_1,y_1)\}.$$

Is there a category with the property that if $\mathbb{R}$ is viewed as an object of that category, we have that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the Euclidean distance function? $$d(x,y) = \sqrt{d^2_\mathbb{R}(x_0,y_0)+d^2_\mathbb{R}(x_1,y_1)}.$$

*Edit*. To be more precise, what I'm looking for is not just an abstract category, but a category whose objects are structures over some signature that includes a function symbol $d$ of airity 2. It must be provable that every structure in the category has the property that the interpretation of $d$ is a metric. Furthermore, one of those structures must be $\mathbb{R}$, and we must have $d_\mathbb{R}(x,y)=|x−y|$. And, we want that the product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is a structure in which $d$ has the interpretation that $d(x,y)$ equals the big expression involving a square root defined above.

Comment: In the category of metric spaces and *continuous* maps, $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric is ***a*** product of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (my point is that the product may not have a uniquely determined metric, or rather, the isomorphisms of objects in the category may not preserve the metric).

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by a unitary map?

Comment: @savick01 A linear isometry (into, not necessarily onto).

Comment: @DanielFischer Then you get not the euclidean metric, but a metric $\sqrt 2$ times smaller than the euclidean, right? We want the product of two morphisms a morphism, but the diagonal map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ is not an isometry with the euclidean metric.

Comment: @savick01 Hm, right, that doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielFischer But wait. In your category you don't have products, because a product means projections and a projection is usually not an isometry. So $\mathbb R^2$ is not a product of $\mathbb R$. It is neither the sum (but anyway in the question it is defined as the product).

Comment: Maybe you want the category of Hilbert spaces and linear contractions.

Comment: @GEdgar, are you sure that works? I think that idea was discussed in the comments here and found problematic.

Comment: Could it be the category of euclidean spaces and isometries as morphisms?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand the question. But if the point is that all morphisms $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are required to preserve the Euclidean metric, then that demonstrably cannot occur. If it *doesn't* mean that, then I would need to have the phrase "is equipped with" made more precise.

Comment: @user43208, look at it this way. What I'm looking for is not just an abstract category, but a category whose objects are structures over some signature. That signature must include a function symbol $d$ of airity $2,$ and it must be provable that every structure in category has the property that the interpretation of $d$ is a metric. One of those structures must be $\mathbb{R}$, where $d$ has interpretation $d_\mathbb{R}(x,y) = |x - y|$. The product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ must be a structure where $d$ has interpretation $d(x,y)=\sqrt{d^2_R(x_0,y_0)+d^2_R(x_1,y_1)}.$

Comment: Okay, thanks; that helps. Probably that precise description should be included in the question statement. You want $d$ to be part of the signature, as opposed to just being definable in the language? You're okay with both function symbols and relation symbols in the signature?

Comment: @user43208, thanks, I put some clarification in the question. And yes, you can have both function symbols and relation symbols, and whatever else you want. But I don't want a silly answer: "Consider the singleton category..." or some such.